# Organization of controller logic in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Suppose a *customer* can log in to their account where they can view their orders, manage payments, change security settings, etc. *Admins* can do the same, but their front-end (i.e. views) will be different from that of customers, because they need privileged access and greater control of data.

Now, with [RESTful design](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers), Laravel recommends to split routes by entities that they represent:

```
// Orders
Router::get('orders', 'OrderController@index');
Router::get('orders/{order}', 'OrderController@show');
// Payments
Router::get('payments', 'PaymentController@index');
Router::get('payments/{payment}', 'PaymentController@show');
// etc.
```

If I follow this pattern, then

- **each** controller method (e.g. `OrderController@index`, `PaymentController@show`) will have an `if-else` construct -- one to handle the logic when `Auth::user()` is a customer, and the other -- when an admin; this will result in *code redundancy*
- some methods may *never* be used by customers (e.g. `delete` or `put`), while they are likely to be needed for admins; this will just add *confusion* to code

An alternative that I can think of is to have something like this:

```
// Customer routes
Router::get('account/orders', 'AccountController@index_orders');
Router::get('account/payments', 'AccountController@index_payments');
// Admin routes
Router::get('admin/orders', 'AdminController@index_orders');
Router::get('admin/payments', 'AdminController@index_payments');
// etc. etc.
```

The problem with this approach is that controllers will get convoluted and large with all the different methods for various entities (e.g. `Order`, `Payment`, etc.).

Lastly, I can think of the followind 3rd option:

```
// Customer routes
Router::get('orders', 'OrderController@index');
Router::get('payments', 'PaymentController@index');
// Admin routes
Router::get('a/orders', 'Admins/OrderController@index');
Router::get('a/payments', 'Admins/PaymentController@index');
// etc. etc.

/* dir structure: */
/app
    /Http
        /Controllers
              /Admins
                   OrderController.php         --  admins only 
                   PaymentController.php       --  admins only 
              OrderController.php     -- customers
              PaymentController.php   -- customers
```

This complies with the RESTful design and separates admins into their own route group (with `admin/` prefix before each route). The problem, clearly, is that some controller logic will be duplicated.

What is the best approach to dealing with this? Any other ways to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last option is a better idea. Most structuring is preferential, but many will agree that a separate namespace and route group for the admin actions is a good idea. You can also use [`Route::resource()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers) which will give you some default methods for a REST API endpoint (you can also remove the ones you don't need). It'd basically be the same thing as you had for the third option but with a route group and resource controllers:

```
// Customer routes
Route::resource('orders', 'OrderController');
Route::resource('payments', 'PaymentController');

// Admin routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Route::resource('orders', 'OrderController');
    Route::resource('payments', 'PaymentController');
});
```

and your directory structure would look like this:

```
app/
└── Http/
    └── Controllers/
        ├── Admin/
            ├── OrderController.php       -- Admins
            └── PaymentController.php     -- Admins
        ├── OrderController.php           -- Customers
        └── PaymentController.php         -- Customers
```

Edit: Didn't see you already knew about the resource controllers. I still recommend doing it this way.